# C# : How to make a POST request in SharpGs client library to initiate resumable uploads in Google Cloud Storage?

Tags: c#, post, google-cloud-storage

I am trying to implement Resumable Uploads from my C# Console Application based on [SharpGs](https://github.com/acropolium/SharpGs) client library. 
so far i can able to PUT data from my console app to Google cloud storage with file size > 2 GB.

While Initiating POST Request , to implement resumable uploads, the server is responding with  this.

"The remote server returned an error: (403) Forbidden."}    System.Net.WebException .

The Uri I am sending is "https://mybucket_name.commondatastorage.googleapis.com/Test1Gb.rar" with POST request.

"Test1Gb.rar "---- is the File Name.

As mentioned in Google Cloud Developers Guide, i am sending the POST Request as following.

```
private HttpWebRequest PostCreateRequest(string authValue, DateTime date, string contentType,int contentLength)
    {
        var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(_uri);
        request.Method = PureRequestMethod(_method).ToString();
        request.Headers.Add(@"Authorization", authValue);
        request.Headers.Add(@"x-goog-resumable", "start");
        request.Date = date;
        request.ContentLength = 0;
        request.ContentType = contentType;
        return request;
    }


public string PostRequest(string authValue, DateTime date, string contentType,int contentLength, Bucket.ObjectHead objectHead)
    {
        try
        {
            var request = PostCreateRequest(authValue, date, contentType,contentLength);

            using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
            {  
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.Created)
                {
                    return String.Empty;
                }
                else
                    return StreamToString(response.GetResponseStream());
            }
        }
        catch (WebException exception)
        {
            return StreamToString(exception.Response.GetResponseStream());
        }
    }
```

I Have been trying this for 1 week. I don't know what is wrong with this.

Is there any help I can get from anyone?

Thankyou.

Answer (score 0):

403 usually indicates a permission problem. It could be that you don't have permission to create objects in the destination bucket or it could be that an object by that name already exists in the destination bucket and you don't have permission to overwrite it. I would try using gsutil to obtain and examine the ACLs associated with the bucket and object you are trying to upload to. The syntax would be 'gsutil getacl gs://mybucket_name' and 'gsutil getacl gs://mybucket_name/Test1Gb.rar'.

Another common pitfall is that people have multiple projects and they use one project to create the bucket and another project to obtain the OAauth token used to manipulate (in this case upload an object into) the bucket.

Another strategy would be to try using a non-resumable upload to the same object using POST. If that works, then you know the problem is related to your use of the resumable upload protocol. If that fails, then it's more likely an ACL/permission issue, independent of resumable uploads.

Comment: Thank you for replay. I can able to upload file using PUT Request. So, i should also able to upload files using POST Request. Do i need separate bucket Access control list for PUT and POST Request to deal with objects in that bucket?

Comment: Anyway I will do what you have suggested.

Comment: Marc.
I did what you have suggested(Upload files using POST Request), but could not able to do that as well. Its saying **400 Bad Request**. I just replaced the PUT method with POST, without changing any thing in my Program. 

As i am uploading files from my console application  using PUT request , do i need to add separate Procedure for implementing POST Request?
Also i am using  Google Cloud Storage API Version 1.0, which i think , is not a problem.